# ASP.NET Core 2.1 Referring to ApplicationDbContext from Class Library

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have these 2 projects App.ClassLibrary and App.Data

I followed this tutorial https://garywoodfine.com/using-ef-core-in-a-separate-class-library-project/ to move my migrations and models to App.ClassLibrary. One of those steps was to create an ApplicationDbContext in the class library:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options) { }
    public DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserRoles> UserRoles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Applications> Applications { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Roles> Roles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<EventLogs> EventLogs { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(schema: DatabaseGlobals.SchemaName);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Users>();
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserRoles>();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Applications>();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Roles>();
        modelBuilder.Entity<EventLogs>();
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        Audit();
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }

    public async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        Audit();
        return await base.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    private void Audit()
    {
        var entries = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.Entity is Users && (x.State == EntityState.Added || x.State == EntityState.Modified));
        foreach (var entry in entries)
        {
            if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
            {
                ((Users)entry.Entity).CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
            }
        ((Users)entry.Entity).UpdatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;
        }
    }
}
```

In App.Data, I am trying to reference ApplicationDbContext but so far this isn't working

```
private ApplicationDbContext dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
```

I used to have a similar project in ASP.NET MVC 5 with an ApplicationDBContext like this:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUsersExtendedDetails> AspNetUsersExtendedDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetApplications> AspNetApplications { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetEventLogs> AspNetEventLogs { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetRolesExtendedDetails> AspNetRolesExtendedDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserRolesExtendedDetails> AspNetUserRolesExtendedDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserAccessTokens> AspNetUserAccessTokens { get; set; }
    public ApplicationDbContext() : base("ManagementStudio")
    {

    }
    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

}
```

I could use

```
private ApplicationDbContext dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
```

without any issues but now I'm guessing because of the different versions and framework its not working. Not sure what I can do to get the dbcontext.

EDIT:

This is the error I get in my .Net Core 2.1 App

There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'options' of 'ApplicationDbContext.ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions)'

Comment: Why isn't it working? Do you get an error? What error? BTW ASP.NET Core uses dependency injection extensively and contexts are *injected*. You *shouldn't* have private fields like that. ASP.NET Core knows about injected contexts and closes them when a request ends. It doesn't know about your `dbContext` field

Comment: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'options' of 'ApplicationDbContext.ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext>)' This is the error

Comment: I'm not sure what parameters I should insert in my app.data declaration

Comment: An `options` parameter. That's why you *shouldn't* try to create repositories like this. Check [Configuring a DbContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext). It shows how you configure context options in the service configuration section. ASP.NET Core will use that information to construct the context and inject it into your controller

Comment: Sorry I'm confused. I'm looking through the guide now. What would my blog.db be in this case?

Comment: It seems like its asking my to link the name of the db file?

Comment: You aren't reading the article, you are looking for code to copy. That example uses Sqlite. There are similar `Use` methods for any provider, eg `UseSqlServer`

Comment: Check for example the Data Access section of the [ASP.NET Core 2.1 tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/intro?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio#examine-the-context-registered-with-dependency-injection). Follow the tutorial to understand how ASP.NET Core is supposed to work before refactoring the data access code to another assembly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `DbContext` is fine, but you have to register it with dependency injection and inject it into your classes instead of using new.

Your `startup.cs` `ConfigureServices` method should have your database with the connection string.

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Then, on the classes you want to use them (like a `Controller`) you inject it into the constuctor.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

    public HomeController(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ApplicationDbContext` should be:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUsersExtendedDetails> AspNetUsersExtendedDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetApplications> AspNetApplications { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetEventLogs> AspNetEventLogs { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetRolesExtendedDetails> AspNetRolesExtendedDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserRolesExtendedDetails> AspNetUserRolesExtendedDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserAccessTokens> AspNetUserAccessTokens { get; set; }
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {

    }
}
```

And your should register it like that, depending on the DB server you use, for SqlServer:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>  
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DbContext"))
```

Comment: The `DbSet` properties *don't* have to be virtual. Registering it won't work unless dependency injection is used. There's nothing wrong with strongly typed DbContextOptions either.